# Аналог getch в python

Tags: python

Как организовать функцию, подобную `getch()` в С++? Или, может, библиотеки какие есть? Нужно, чтобы программа ожидала ввода одного любого символа.

Comment: тот же вопрос [Python read a single character from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/510357/4279) -- можно посмотреть на примеры без `curses`  и поддерживающие ввод не-ascii символов (`getwch()`).

Answer (score 3):

Организовать можно примерно так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# CursesExample1
#------------------------------- 
# Curses Programming Sample 1 
#------------------------------- 
import curses 
myscreen = curses.initscr() 
myscreen.border(0) 
myscreen.addstr(12, 25, "See Curses, See Curses Run!") 
myscreen.refresh() 
myscreen.getch() 
curses.endwin()
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](http://help.ubuntu.ru/fullcircle/39/python_%D1%87_13).

**Обновление:**

А если у Вас Windows, то все проще:

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    pressedKey = msvcrt.getch()
    if pressedKey == 'q':    
        print "Q was pressed"
    elif pressedKey == 'x':    
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "Key Pressed:" + str(pressedKey)
```

Comment: According to http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html the curses module is only supported on Unix platforms... а у меня-то винда(

Comment: Обновил ответ.