# Press enter to continue

Tags: python, python-3.6

У меня есть такой код:

```
while True:
    a = input()
    if a == '3':
        print('ok')
    else:
        input('press 4')
        print('nice)
```

Я хотел бы для продолжения нажать клавишу «4», а не «Enter» при input(),
как я могу это сделать? Мне нужно приостановить программу и подождать, пока пользователь нажмет кнопку «4» на клавиатуре, а не enter.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412355/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-getch-%D0%B2-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user/25342814#25342814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install keyboard
```

Вот, например, механизм, благодаря которому можно такое реализовать:

```
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    if e.name == '4':
        print('Nice')
    elif e.name == '3':
        print('Ok')

keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install readchar
```

```
import readchar
print("Reading a char:")
print(repr(readchar.readchar()))
print("Reading a key:")
print(repr(readchar.readkey()))
```

---

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user/25342814#25342814)