# Как сделать нажатие сугубо на только нужную кнопку python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Во время того как пишу `input` нужно чтобы пользователь нажимал на кнопку `K` и далее программа продолжалась. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/412400/16574

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/510404/2101808 вот этот ответ больше мне нравится

Answer (score -1):

```
a = input("Введите K: ")
# английская клавиша
if a == "k":
    print("Вы нажали на клавишу K")
if a == "K":
    print("Вы нажали на клавишу K")
# русская клавиша
if a == "к":
    print("Вы нажали на клавишу K")
if a == "К":
    print("Вы нажали на клавишу K")
else:
    print("Нажмите клавишу K для продолжения")
```

Comment: тут энтер щё надо жать...

Comment: Зато не так муторно

Comment: особенно если делаешь консольную игрушку))

Comment: )))))))))))))))